# React Router Redux go action is shown in the LogMonitor but doesn't change the path on browser

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) on one of my views I just want to redirects users is somethig is not set My components is fairly simple

```
// MyComponentWithRedirect.js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {go} from 'react-router-redux'

class MyComponentWithRedirect extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    userInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount() {        
    if (this.props.userInfo.firstTime) {
      this.props.dispatch(go('/welcome'))
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({userInfo: state.userInfo})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponentWithRedirect)
```

I can see the LOCATION_CHANGE action triggered but doesn't show the destination view

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've found I missed the setup of [syncHistoryWithStore](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#history--synchistorywithstorehistory-store-options) after that it's works like a charm using the react-router API

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

...
browserHistory.push('/welcome')
```

I dont need dispatch any more for change the location